# Is there a way to force a class to presented right after another element without hiding it?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this website: http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/

In low resolutions (e.g. mobile devices), the header hides behind the images I have at the top of my page.

I tried the following code with no luck yet:

```
#masthead {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding a ` z-index:1; `?

Comment: please create a [mcve] in the question - see [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I thoroughly misred the question. Try adding a display: flex; style to the box that contains the images you want displayed at the top. You will then need to remove/adjust the image height width as they are set in HTML and will likely not fit on the page. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  the `CSS` for the header from

```
#text-7 {
position: relative;
top: -210px;
}
```

To

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#text-7 {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
} }
```

And change padding to margin for the following element to account for menu:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.business-template .widget.widget_call_to_action_block .call-to-action-content-wrapper {
padding: 25px 0;
margin: 200px 0 0;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `#masthead` you are fixing the top position to `150px` this is what causing your issue. you can increase the top to `200px` or find a dynamic way.